# How to start a new jthread on a class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I think the question is quite obvious. The I have tried so far:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

class test
{
public:
    void member(std::stop_token stoken)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

    void run()
    {
        // None compiles correctly
        // std::jthread jt(&member);
        // std::jthread jt(&test::member, this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    t.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible with the new jthread & with using stop_token?
Ps.: Of course it's possible to workaround it by making the member function static or by removing the stop_token. But I'm curious if there's a real & clean solution instead of extra N lines of hacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) to bind `this` to `&test::member` and pass it to `jthread`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
class test
{
public:
    void member(std::stop_token stoken)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::jthread jt(std::bind_front(&test::member, this));
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    t.run();
}
```

Comment: You should add more detail about _why_ `bind_front` is a solution for this problem

Comment: @Tootsie, see [@apple apple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600425/1098603).

Answer (score 4):

in addition to existing answer, the reason the code in question doesn't work is because `jthread` would try to pass `stop_token` as first parameter

---

```cpp
std::jthread jt(&test::member, this);
```

would do

```cpp
// with stop_token
// note: stop token is passed as first parameter
std::invoke(&test::member, the_inner_token, this)

// or (without stop_token)
std::invoke(&test::member, this)
```

which doesn't work because `&test::member` need to be invoke as

```
std::invoke(&test::member, this, token)
```

---

as a result

```
#include <thread>

static void before(std::stop_token, int);
static void raw(int);
static void after(int,std::stop_token);

void run(){
    std::jthread(before, 0); // work
    std::jthread(raw, 0);    // work
    std::jthread(after, 0);  // not work
}
```